# Erro NullPointerException usando tipo Boolean

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou tendo problemas novamente com esse projeto, o aplicativo executa normalmente abre a tela para cadastro e tudo mais, porem quando vc clica no botão para salvar ele simplesmente fecha o app, mas no console do firebase é cadastrado os dados...
já analisei e não achei o erro, alguém ai sabe onde se encontra esse erro ?

Agradeço desde já...

//Erro:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
  'boolean    java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference at
   com.example.matheus.kypyy.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
```

//Classe de Usuarios

```
public class Usuarios {

private String nome;
private String Data;
private String Rg;
private String Cpf;
private String Endereco;
private String Doenca;
private String Profissao;

public void Usuarios(){

}

public String getCpf() {
    return Cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    Cpf = cpf;
}

public String getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    Data = data;
}

public String getDoenca() {
    return Doenca;
}

public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
    Doenca = doenca;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return Endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    Endereco = endereco;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getProfissao() {
    return Profissao;
}

public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
    Profissao = profissao;
}

public String getRg() {
    return Rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    Rg = rg;
 }
}
```

//CLasse do BD Firebase

```
public class FireHelper {
DatabaseReference bd;
Boolean saved;
ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioss = new ArrayList<>();

public FireHelper(DatabaseReference bd) {
    this.bd = bd;
}
public Boolean save(Usuarios usuarios){
    if(usuarios == null){
        saved = false;
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            bd.child("Usuarios").push().setValue(usuarios);
        }catch (DatabaseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved = false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    usuarioss.clear();

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Usuarios usuarios = ds.getValue(Usuarios.class);
        usuarioss.add(usuarios);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Usuarios> retorno(){
    bd.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return usuarioss;
 }
}
```

// Classe Main onde vai exibir os dados

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference bd;
FireHelper helper;
AdapterCustom adapter;
ListView lv;
EditText textViewNome, textViewData, textViewRg, textViewCpf, textViewEndereco, textViewDoenca, textViewProfissao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Banco de dados
    bd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    helper = new FireHelper(bd);
    //layout
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    //Adaptador
    adapter = new AdapterCustom(this, helper.retorno());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayInputDialog();
        }
    });
}



private void displayInputDialog() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Salvar no banco de dados");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);

    //Declarando objetos
    final TextView textViewNome = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    final TextView textViewData = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    final TextView textViewRg = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextRg);
    final TextView textViewCpf = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextCpf);
    final TextView textViewEndereco = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextEndereco);
    final TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextDoenca);
    final TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextProfissao);

    Button saveButton = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);


    //Salvar...
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nome = textViewNome.getText().toString();
            String data = textViewData.getText().toString();
            String rg = textViewRg.getText().toString();
            String cpf = textViewCpf.getText().toString();
            String endereco = textViewEndereco.getText().toString();
            String doenca = textViewDoenca.getText().toString();
            String profissao = textViewProfissao.getText().toString();
            Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
            u.setNome(nome);
            u.setData(data);
            u.setRg(rg);
            u.setCpf(cpf);
            u.setEndereco(endereco);
            u.setDoenca(doenca);
            u.setProfissao(profissao);

            if (nome != null && nome.length() > 0) {
                if (helper.save(u)) {
                    textViewNome.setText("");
                    textViewData.setText("");
                    textViewRg.setText("");
                    textViewCpf.setText("");
                    textViewEndereco.setText("");
                    textViewDoenca.setText("");
                    textViewProfissao.setText("");

                    adapter = new AdapterCustom(MainActivity.this, helper.retorno());
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sem dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    d.show();
  }

}
```

//Classe do Adapter

```
public class AdapterCustom extends BaseAdapter {
Context c;
ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioss;

public AdapterCustom(Context c, ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarioss) {
    this.c = c;
    this.usuarioss = usuarioss;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return usuarioss.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return usuarioss.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView== null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }
    //Declarando objetos
    TextView textViewNome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
    TextView textViewData = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
    TextView textViewRg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRg);
    TextView textViewCpf = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCpf);
    TextView textViewEndereco = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEndereco);
    TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDoenca);
    TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfissao);

    final Usuarios u = (Usuarios) this.getItem(position);

    textViewNome.setText(u.getNome());
    textViewData.setText(u.getData());
    textViewRg.setText(u.getRg());
    textViewCpf.setText(u.getCpf());
    textViewEndereco.setText(u.getEndereco());
    textViewDoenca.setText(u.getDoenca());
    textViewProfissao.setText(u.getProfissao());

    //Função onclick

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c, u.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    return convertView;
 }
}
```

Comment: Não aparece nada o console de erro?

Comment: Sim, já listei o erro na pergunta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O campo `saved` está declarado como sendo do tipo [Boolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Boolean.html).

Ao contrário do tipo primitivo *boolean*(b minúsculo), que é automaticamente inicializado com o valor `false`, o tipo *Boolean*(B maiúsculo) é `null`, caso não seja inicializado ou instanciado.

A razão do erro é essa mesmo: está a aceder a um método(`booleanValue()`), da classe *Boolean*, num objecto que é nulo.

Pelo que vejo no código, nada indica que necessite de usar a classe em vez do tipo primitivo.

Assim, altere a declaração de `saved` de

```
Boolean saved;
```

para

```
boolean saved;
```

Também não vejo razão para dar o erro que indica.

Esse erro seria lançado caso usasse `saved`, antes de inicializa-lo, em situações destas:

```
if(saved){
    ...
    ...
}
```

ou

```
boolean qualquerCoisa = saved;
```

Não encontro nenhum caso destes(ou outro) no seu código , apenas vejo inicializações.

Comment: Bom, pelo que percebi sua resposta só detalhou a minha resposta que já resolveria talvez, eu digo talvez, do nosso amigo Matheus. Pelo que percebi após alguns testes, sua afirmativa "...ela necessita de ser instanciada antes de poder ser utilizada." não é verdadeira. Fiz [uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160914/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-boolean-e-boolean) para esclarecer um pouco mais sobre a diferença.

Comment: @seamusd. Qual é o problema de eu dar uma resposta mais detalhada? Eu digo que deve instanciá-la porque falo em classe em termos genéricos, Boolean é um caso particular em que pode ser feito como você disse, caso esse que deveria ter explicado ao AP e não começar a resposta por "Tente colocar ..." . Por outro lado a forma como você fala só é possível a partir do java 1.5, a isso se chama autoboxing.

Comment: @seamusd Editei a resposta. Você têm alguma razão, na forma como estava poderia criar alguma confusão.

Comment: Agora sim você também tem alguma razão, vou até te dar um  +1. Abs.

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar um valor *default* para sua variável `saved`:

```
private Boolean saved = true;
```