# Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?

Tags: java, tipagem, booleano

Realizei alguns testes usando `Boolean` e `boolean` e aparentemente retornou o mesmo resultado. Vejam abaixo:

```
Boolean bool  = true;
boolean bool2 = true;

if(bool)
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Funciona!");    

if(bool2)
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Funciona também!");
```

O `Boolean` (com B maiúsculo) sendo uma classe, neste caso acima NÃO necessitou ser instanciada antes utilizá-la. Existe alguma diferença entre `Boolean` e `boolean`? O que pode influenciar na minha aplicação no momento da declaração dos mesmo?

Comment: Sei que `Boolean` pode receber `null` enquanto `boolean` não, e pode usar apenas `Boolean` nos `Generics`, por exemplo `Convert<Boolean>()`...

Comment: Pergunta similar e resposta similar : [int e Integer - Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62861/14213)

Comment: Eu costumo dizer que `Boolean` sem o devido preparo mental é um pedido para NPE inesperado e inexplicável

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`boolean` é um tipo primitivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), ou seja é um número que ocupa 1 byte (ainda que não seja especificado que tenha esse tamanho) e é considerado um tipo por valor, ou seja, seu valor é sua própria identidade, ele existe em si só. A comparação de valores é direta.

O valor padrão dele é `false` (que seria um 0).

Ele pode ser convertido implicitamente para um texto ("false" ou "true") ou um número (0 ou 1) pode ser usado para representar falso ou verdadeiro no tipo, onde for necessário.

[`Boolean` é uma classe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) que encapsula um `boolean` e é um tipo por referência, portanto o seu valor de fato é um ponteiro que aponta para um objeto cujo valor é o booleano. Obviamente a classe deriva `Object` e tem todas características de um objeto como outro qualquer.

É uma forma de passar o dado por referência em [parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) de métodos ou usar onde precisa de uma indireção.

O valor padrão dele `null`. Ele tem 3 estados possíveis e o fato de precisar do estado `null` é um motivo para usá-lo.

A comparação se dá pelo método `equals()`, se usar o operador `==` vai comparar os ponteiros dos objetos, mesmo tendo o mesmo valor. A não ser que use [`booleanValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue--) que pega o primitivo dentro do objeto, mas aí a comparação não é com o objeto e sim com primitivos extraídos das classes.

O compilador faz um truque para o *boxing* parecer transparente, mas ele está criando uma nova instância no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

```
Boolean x = true; //na verdade é traduzido para o abaixo
Boolean x = Boolean.valueOf(true);
```

Imagine que além do espaço ocupado pelo ponteiro (4 ou 8 bytes) ele ainda armazena um objeto que pode ocupar 20 bytes ou mais dependendo da arquitetura. Tudo isso por causa de um único bit.

A indireção além de ter um custo maior de alocação e cópia gera mais *cache miss* no acesso que precisa ocorrer em duas etapas: acessa o valor (endereço do ponteiro) e depois o valor do objeto.

A preferência é sempre usar o tipo primitivo, é mais rápido e ocupa menos memória. Dada a ineficiência a opção pela classe só se for realmente necessário ter uma referência (em outras linguagens é possível ter uma referência sem criar esse problema todo, mas não em Java). Um exemplo de necessidade na versão atual é o uso com *generics* (isso possivelmente mudará em Java 15 ou superior).

```
ArrayList<Boolean> = lista = new ArrayList<>(); //válido
ArrayList<boolean> = lista = new ArrayList<>(); //inválido
```

Veja sobre isso em [Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) e [Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101).

Com métodos:

```
void metodo(boolean x) {x = false;} //quando terminar o método, não muda nada no argumento
void metodo(Boolean x) {x = false;} //quando terminar o método, o argumento valerá false
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/RefereceVsValue.java).

Rumores :) [É ideal usar tipos primitivos em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101)

Para efeito de comparação C# consegue todos os 3 principais efeitos relatados com o tipo primitivo: uso como tipo genérico, pode ser passado explicitamente por referência sem fazer *boxing* e tem a opção anulável `bool?` que ainda é um tipo por valor ocupando apenas 2 bytes no total (poderia ser 1 se houvesse otimização).

Answer (score 23):

- `Boolean` com letra maiúscula no começo é uma classe, é o mesmo que `java.lang.Boolean`
- `boolean` é um tipo primitivo de comparação de dois valores, `true` ou `false`.

Você pode usar ambas com mesmo objetivo, a diferença é que a classe tem métodos para converter para string por exemplo, ou converter de string (ou fazer um parse)

### Métodos da classe java.lang.Boolean

- `bool booleanValue()` o valor de retorno deste método é um booleano primitivo.
- `static int compare(boolean x, boolean y)` compara dois valores booleanos.
- `int compareTo(Boolean b)` compara o valor da classe atual com outra classe.
- `boolean equals(Object obj)` retorna `true` se e somente se o argumento não é nulo e é um objeto booleano que representa o mesmo valor booleano como este objeto.
- `static boolean getBoolean(String name)` Retorna `true` se e somente se a propriedade do sistema nomeado pelo argumento existe e é igual à string `"true"`.
- `int hashCode()` retorna uma hash para o objeto atual.
- `static boolean parseBoolean(String s)` faz um parse da string para booleano.
- `String toString()` retorna a `String` que representa o objeto.
- `static String toString(boolean b)` retorna a `String` que representa o valor do argumento.
- `static Boolean valueOf(boolean b)` retorna a instancia `java.lang.Boolean` que representa o valor booleano específico.
- `static Boolean valueOf(String s)` retorna o `java.lang.Boolean` representado pela String no argumento