# O que é booleano?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação, booleano

O que é booleano exatamente? Poderiam dar exemplos práticos?

Faz diferença escrever `true` ou `True`?

Comment: Tem explicação em java para isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160914/qual-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-boolean-e-boolean

Comment: Case-Insensitive não tem relação com valores booleanos.

Comment: Eu entendi agora LINQ, é porque nos tópicos que vejo, sempre vejo esses termos juntos, mas obrigado!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho mostre onde vem junto. Se estiver tudo certo vou editar a pergunta pra ficar mais óbvia.

Comment: @bigown Não, não sei exatamente onde, entende? É que por exemplo, pesquisei no Google sobre Booleando, e aparece  junto algumas vezes, dizendo que é case-sensitive. Mas descarta isso, eu que me enrolei todo mesmo e acabei confundindo a cabeça do pessoal. Mil desculpas.

Comment: Agora eu li melhor, é case-insensitive. Ja entendi os termos. Ja marquei a resposta como aceita, vou encerrar aqui. Desculpe bigown e obrigado a paciência.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Booleano, no contexto que entendi que está perguntado, é um [tipo de dado que representa apenas dois estados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type), verdadeiro ou falso. Isso tem uma relação direta com os bits do computador que só possuem dois estados 0 ou 1.

Muitas pessoas programam mas não sabem que o computador só entende essas duas informações, e só sabe fazer três operações, a adição (*or*), multiplicação (*and*) e inversão (*not*) de bit ([circuitos booleanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit)). Todo o resto que existe no computador é composição disso tudo.

Aí já vai um início sobre [álgebra booleana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) criada pelo George Boole. É parecido com o que fazemos no decimal, mas só possui dois dígitos e operações mais simples.

Acho que já deu para entender como ele é fundamental na programação. E aqui no site tem muita coisa falando sobre isso, ainda que nada que dê a definição.

Usamos isso o tempo todo [em condições](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression), mas mesmo que não estejamos percebendo está sendo usado concretamente. É que em expressões booleanas elas ficam evidentes e é isso que acho que quer saber.

Algumas pessoas [acham que só existe booleano em `if` o que não é verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44742/101).

[Tem muita coisa sobre booleano em computação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean) porque ele é a base de tudo o que fazemos.

Eu prefiro *linkar* os artigos em inglês que costumam ser muito melhores, mas é fácil navegar para a versão em português.

## Case insensitive

Imaginando que esteja falando sobre `True`, ou `true` ou `TRUE`, ou mesmo `.T.`, ou `1`, ou seja a representação sintática. Não importa, isso não muda nada para a álgebra booleana, é só a convenção de cada linguagem, o conceito e o resultado é o mesmo.

Nas linguagens que não possuem sensibilidade de caixa pode escrever com maiúsculos e minúsculos que funciona, mas eu acho que deve ser consistente e manter um padrão adotado por todo mundo, por isso até sou um pouco contra linguagens insensíveis, a não ser pra *microscripts*.

Em linguagens sensíveis precisa ver qual é a palavra ou símbolo que é considerado com literal booleano. Se é `true`, escrever `True` é outra coisa muito diferente e não representa um verdadeiro.

Se por acaso estiver falando de `Boolean` e `boolean`, aí já foi respondido em [Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado bigown, pela resposta e desculpe pela "lambança"

Answer (score 1):

Booleano* Em ciência da computação, booleano é um tipo de dado primitivo que possui dois valores, que podem ser considerados como 0 ou 1, falso ou verdadeiro.

Comment: Mas é case-insensitive? Ou não?

Comment: Você se refere a que linguagem ? java por exemplo tem 'boolean teste = true;'  ou 'Boolean teste = true;' daria no mesmo

Comment: É a mesma coisa? True, true, TRUE ou depende da linguagem?

Comment: falando em java é 'true' ou 'false'

Comment: Não me recordo que em outra linguagem seja TRUE, ou True, acho que é true ou false;.

Comment: Em Python é `True`, em T-SQL tanto faz (`true`, `TRUE`, `tRuE` e por aí vai).

Comment: @LINQ é um semi-deus