# Como realizar a ação apenas se o valor inserido na EditText esteja dentro de um determinado intervalo de numeros (10 a 100 por exemplo)?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, edittext

Tenho uma duvida que pode ser bem besta, mas ja me tirou uns bons neuronios. 
**Como realizar a ação apenas se o valor inserido na minha EditText (fio2ET) estiver dentro de um determinado intervalo (por exemplo: maior que 10 e menor que 100)? 
 Alem disso, exibir uma toast caso o valor inserido seja menor que o determinado.**
No codigo abaixo, eu coloquei para realizar a ação caso a EditText não esteja vazia, mas isso não é muito o que eu queria.

```
 binding.fio2ET.addTextChangedListener (object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if(binding.pao2ET.text.isNotEmpty() && binding.fio2ET.text.isNotEmpty()){
                val etPAO2 = (binding.pao2ET.text.toString()).toInt()
                val etFIO2 = (binding.fio2ET.text.toString()).toDouble()

                val res = calc(etPAO2, etFIO2)
                val resint = res.toInt()
                binding.tvRES.text = resint.toString()

            }
                else if (binding.fio2ET.text.isEmpty()){
                    binding.fio2ET.hint = "digite...";
                    binding.tvRES.text = ""
            }
                else {
                    binding.tvRES.text = ""
                }
        }
```

Comment: Sou bastante leigo em programação! To criando meu app basicamente com videos do youtube e lendo bastante aqui no StackOverFlow hahaha Entao nao, nao tentei isso nao! A questao seria, como fazer essa verificação? Isso provavelmente resolve meu problema!

Answer (score 0):

> Como realizar a ação apenas se o valor inserido na `EditText` esteja
> dentro de um determinado intervalo de números (10 a 100 por exemplo)?

**Usando uma [Declaração Condicional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrutura_de_sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o).**

Declarações Condicionais são estruturas de linguagem de programação para lidar com decisões.
As Declarações Condicionais executam diferentes fluxos de processamento dependendo da veracidade de condições [booleanas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214972/o-que-%C3%A9-booleano) definidas pelo programador.

Olhando a documentação [Kotlin Loops e Condicionais](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html) encontra-se dois tipos de declarações condicionais:

- [Estrutura de condicional simples `if`.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#if-expression)
- [Estrutura de condicionais múltiplas `when`.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Nesse caso a solução mais simples se dá com o uso da Estrutura de Condicional simples `if`.

Veja o seguinte Pseudocódigo.

```
Se (condição) Então
    /*
       bloco de código a ser executado caso a condição seja verdadeira.
    */
Senão
    /*
       bloco de código a ser executado caso a condição seja falsa.
    */
Fim Se
```

<sup>Pseudocódigo de uma declaração condicional `if`.</sup>

A estrutura condicional simples testa logicamente uma determinada `condição` para decidir qual dos blocos deva ser executado.

Testando se um valor `v` está contido dentro do intervalo fechado `[]`

```
val v = 33
 
if (v >= 0 && v <= 100) {
   print("O valor V está entre 0 e 100.")
} else {
   print("O valor V não está entre 0 e 100.")
}
//O valor V está entre 0 e 100.
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/rEzFyd)</sup>

Também pode se usar uma expressão condicional ternária, que em outras linguagens é usado o [operador `?:`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) em Kotlin usa-se o próprio `if` como operador ternário, veja o pseudocódigo:

```
variavel = Se (condição) /*valor em caso de condição verdadeira.*/ Senão /*valor caso a condição seja  falsa.*/
```

<sup>Pseudocódigo de uma operador ternário `if`.</sup>

Trazendo mais próximo do seu problema(Ref. [Visão geral das notificações toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts?hl=pt-br)):

```
val v = binding.fio2ET.text.toInt()
 
val texto = if (v >= 10 && v <= 100) "Valor entre 10 e 100." else "Valor fora de 10 e 100."

Toast.makeText(this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```