# Array e o tipo que está sendo criado

Tags: java, array

Em Java, quando tenho a seguinte instrução:

```
int[] ns = new int[5];
```

surgem as seguintes dúvidas:

1. É criado um objeto de que tipo?
2. Para cada valor em um índice, eu o chamo de instância?

Comment: Como diz o titulo, é criado um array, só que com todas as posições zeradas, assim: `[0,0,0,0,0]`. Os índices não tem instancia porque é um array de tipo primitivo e tipos primitivos não são instanciáveis. Se fosse um array de tipo não primitivo(como por exemplo `String[] arr = new String[5];`) seria um array onde todos os indices estariam nulos, pois o fato de instanciar a lista nao quer dizer que objetos do tipo suportado por ela serão instanciados dentro do array. Veja a prova: https://ideone.com/rBXNuC

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

> É criado um objeto de que tipo?

`ns` terá um objeto do tipo *array* de `int` e não poderá ser mudado. Note que por ser um tipo por referência a variável terá um ponteiro para o objeto real.

> Para cada valor em um índice, eu o chamo de instância?

Para cada valor em um local que pode ser acessado por um índice haverá uma instância de tipo `int`. Por ser um tipo por valor, a instância já fica ali mesmo na variável, ou seja, na variável `ns[0]` terá um inteiro de 4 bytes, em `ns[1]` também, e assim por diante.

```
System.out.println(1);
System.out.println("x");
System.out.println(new Object());
System.out.println(new ArrayList());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Representation.java).

O primeiro tem um objeto instanciado do tipo `int` e ele é usado para imprimir. O objeto originalmente está na parte estática do código. Quando chama-se o método `println()` uma cópia dele é passada como argumento, portanto o parâmetro receberá uma nova instância de `int` idêntica ao original. Temos certeza que é uma nova instância porque o valor do argumento poderia mudar sem problemas (neste caso não muda porque é uma constante) e não afetaria o valor que está sendo usado dentro de `println()`, afinal são duas instâncias completamente diferentes. Há uma instância, é um objeto, baseado em tipo primitivo. Não vou entrar no detalhe que alguma implementação pode obrigar fazer [*boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101) e o valor ser copiado para o *heap*, o que é ineficiente.

O segundo é muito parecido. O que muita gente não entende é que o literal de *string* na verdade é um `new String("x")`. O tipo *string* se parece com um tipo primitivo porque ele tem semântica de valor, mas na verdade ele é um tipo por referência. Ele provavelmente será alocado no *heap* por causa do `new`, mas isso não é garantido, pode haver um otimização e ser alocado no *stack* (isto é apenas detalhes de implementação). Note que nesse caso nem haverá uma alocação de fato, porque a *string* estará na parte estática do código e a referência necessária apontará para este endereço.

O terceiro cria um objeto por referência, provavelmente alocado no *heap*, e ele é do tipo `Object`. Como não há estrutura nele, a alocação ficará vazia (mas consome espaço de memória mesmo assim (se não me engano 20 bytes).

O quarto cria um objeto da mesma forma, e ele será derivado de `Object`. Não confunda *object* com `Object`. Um é uma palavra que usamos para designar coisas presumivelmente materiais, o outro é o nome de uma classe raiz usada em algumas linguagens ditas orientadas a objeto, como é o caso do Java.

Veja [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Em Java é igual.

Comment: `haverá uma instância de tipo int.` -  mas int é um tipo primitivo não instanciável, como pode ser considerada uma instância?

Comment: E por que você acha isto?

Comment: Não se usa  `new` para iniciar uma variável primitiva, o próprio exemplo citado mostra isso, quando o array é criado com zeros nas posições.

Comment: E o que o `new` tem a ver com criar uma instância?

Comment: E como é possível existir uma instância de algo em java se ninguém deu `new` nela em algum ponto?

Comment: Defina instância.

Comment: A representação em forma de objeto de uma determinada classe.  Mas o que questiono é se cada posicao do array é considerado uma instancia, entao um tipo null tambem poderia ser considerado uma instancia, dado que um array de tipo nao primitivo é criado com posicoes nulas.

Comment: Onde tem essa definição? Por isso que tem que ler o que eu falo sobre tipos por valor e por referência. São coisas distintas que não podem ser tratadas como se fossem a mesma coisa. Um um a instância está no próprio local de armazenamento, no outro há um apontador no lugar de armazenamento e a instância em outro lugar. No *array*, e não em outro lugar, tem um objeto quando se usa um `int`? Tem um objeto quando se usa um `Integer`?

Comment: "Para cada valor em um local que pode ser acessado por um índice haverá uma instância de tipo int."  Você quis dizer uma instância do tipo array de int?

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira não, eu disse isso mesmo, não quis dizer outra coisa, nem faria sentido dizer o que está pensando.

Comment: @Maniero Desculpa não acompanhar o seu raciocínio, mas como pode haver uma instância de um tipo primitivo?

Comment: @Maniero então, basicamente, uma instancia é um objeto na memória e tudo que possui métodos e atributos pode ser chamado de objeto, mesmo que seja uma variável de tipo primitivo como `int`, ela ainda seria uma instancia para um objeto na memória, este seria o raciocínio?

Comment: @gato Nem precisa ter métodos para ser um objeto. As pessoas se apegam muito a uma definição capenga dada por OO. E [passei a abominar o uso do termo atributo de vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). O raciocínio é este mesmo, eu só mudaria um pouco o texto porque instância e objeto são sinônimos aí. Existe instância de um tipo, baseado em uma definição (classe, estrutura, protótipo, etc.), a instância é um objeto, a instanciação cria um objeto. A próxima versão do Java vai derrubar muita gente do cavalo porque acreditam em coisas que não existem.

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira se não há uma instância então o que é o valor deste tipo armazenado na memória?

Comment: @Maniero você escreveu que não precisa ter métodos para ser um objeto, e que passou a abominar o uso do termo atributo. Poderia me explicar como você diferencia um tipo primitivo de um objeto? Sou novo no assunto, então, sem querer pedir muito, tente usar uma didática mais compreensível.

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira eu poderia, mas o assunto se estendeu, faça uma pergunta nova que eu respondo.

Comment: @Maniero concordo com a primeira resposta (o objeto criado é do tipo array de int). Porém discordo da segunda resposta, que diz que o valor que ocupa um índice é uma instância de int. Compreendo seu pensamento de que se uma linguagem dita orientada à objetos, então todos os dados seriam objetos, e independe de onde está alocado. Mas, a minha pergunta está no contexto da linguagem de programação Java, e, no Java, atualmente, nem todos os dados são considerados objetos, e por isso tais dados são chamados de tipos primitivos. E, por isso, ainda espero uma resposta para a minha segunda pergunta.

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira você pode discordar do que quiser. Eu falo de algo que estudei a vida inteira, que apliquei por 35 anos, e falo baseado em toda a literatura existente, não coisa da minha cabeça. Lamento que ainda não tenha entendido e que tenha dificuldade de interpretação de texto, se quiser continuar aprendendo errado é um direito seu. Outras pessoas que acham o mesmo que você já mudaram de ideia. Todas as linguagens, incluindo Java, incluindo as não OO, tem todos os dados armazenados em objetos. Larga o osso. Em OOP os tipos por referência são derivados de `Object`.

Comment: Vou repetir o que já respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274396/101. `Object` e objeto são coisa distintas. Há uma diferença gramatical e até ortográfica clara o que faz elas terem significados distintos. Você acha que é a mesma coisa, muitas pessoas acham, mas não é. Você não quer uma resposta para aprender, quer uma resposta que confirme o que você acha que é. Eu não farei isso porque é deixar você continuar enganado e estaria enganando outras pessoas.

Comment: @Maniero Concordo com o seu pensamento, mas pare com a arrogância em seus comentários e/ou respostas, e aí sim, terei prazer em lê-los para aprender com eles. Aliás com tanta experiência como escreveu ter, deveria saber que quando se discute um assunto é primordial que a educação e o respeito estejam presentes.