# Diferença entre tipo primitivo e objeto em Java

Tags: java, terminologia, objetos

Em Java, temos os chamados tipos primitivos e os chamados objetos. Qual a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 9):

Vamos entender [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). Portanto todos os dados são objetos.

Há uma ideia errada que só existem objetos em programação orientada a objeto. Se isso fosse verdade, como chamaria o que não é um objeto?

Quando fala em primitivo está usando um adjetivo, então sozinho ele não faz sentido. Portanto quando usa esse termo está referindo-se ao que, como sendo primitivo? É um **objeto primitivo**! Poderíamos chamar de objeto rudimentar em oposição ao objeto complexo, embora algumas linguagens usem o termo primitivo para objetos que também são complexos em algum nível.

Em C# "tudo" é objeto *no sentido de OOP*, ou seja, "tudo" deriva de `Object`, não existe a ideia de tipos primitivos. E o Java agora começou abandonar essa ideia também (ainda existirão os tipos primitivos, mas, aparentemente, eles serão só uma especialização dos tipos por valor que também derivarão de `Object`). Quero ver como chamarão esses novos tipos que não se encaixam na definição de primitivo e nem na de objeto que inicialmente a linguagem definiu, é o que dá definir errado no começo.

**Talvez** tipos primitivos seriam aqueles que não derivam de `Object`. Uma ideia errada para uma linguagem que se diz totalmente OO. Pelo menos Java dá essa ideia. Para uma explicação mais geral: [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101).

Então vamos diferenciar o que é derivado de `Object` e o que é um objeto de forma geral.

Em Java, apenas classes podiam derivar de `Object`, mas isso muda em alguma versão (prometerem para ser na 10, mas agora nem na 19 tem promessa mais, mas um dia vai sair). De qualquer forma todos os dados são objetos, alguns tem taxinomia que indica o nome `Object` em sua hierarquia, outros não possuem isso.

Taxonomia é hierárquica, tudo tem vários níveis de classificação. Cada dado individualizado é um objeto, não importa características específicas, alguns se conformam com `Object`. `Object` e objeto são coisas distintas, em níveis diferentes, definem características diferentes, apenas possuem o mesmo nome.

Costuma-se dizer que:

> Os dois problemas mais difíceis da computação são invalidação de cache e nomear coisas
>
> -- Phil Karlton.

Quando temos dificuldades de usar os nomes corretos, nos contextos corretos, temos dificuldades de entender os problemas de forma correta. Por isso OOP é tão difícil, ele exige que se classifique tudo de forma correta para funcionar bem e se fizer errado é difícil consertar depois. E a internet, ou mesmo outras fontes, está cheia de nomenclaturas erradas ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)). Só o entendimento correto nos leva pelo caminho correto.

Não estou dizendo que o meu entendimento é o correto, qualquer pessoa pode questionar, mas é o que se costuma usar no nosso meio quando a pessoa pensa a respeito do que está usando.

O termo objeto sempre foi usado em todas as linguagens muito antes de OOP virar moda ou até existir. Não podemos ignorar esse termo porque a moda resolveu apropriar o termo para si. Pior ainda se uma linguagem foi mal conceituada e agora está tendo dificuldades de explicar o que é o certo e implementar o mecanismo necessário para o que ela idealizou desde o início funcione.

O tipo baseado em classe gera um objeto que deriva de `Object`. Se um tipo primitivo não gera um objeto, ele gera o que então?

Para dar mais contexto, a dúvida se originou na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274053/101) (veja comentário também) em outra pergunta do AP. Então todo objeto só existe quando é instanciado, e o que muda na instanciação só depende se o tipo é por valor (o termo primitivo ruim) ou por referência. A alocação não pode definir se é um objeto ou não, sempre é, não importa se está na *stack* ou *heap*, se tem uma referência para ele ou não.

Veja mais em [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: como você mesmo diz, "o Java hoje", na teoria, informa que existem os tipos primitivos e que existem os objetos. Se há essa diferença no tratamento desses assuntos por parte do Java, então por que seria incorreto dizer que há diferenças?

Comment: Acho que você não leu a resposta com atenção.

Comment: acho que não estou entendendo bem o que quer dizer. Primeiramente, você escreve que todos os dados são objetos. Isso me faz pensar que você não diferencia tipo primitivo de objeto. No final, você escreve que todo objeto só existe quando é instanciado. Isso me faz pensar que agora você diferencia tipo primitivo de objeto, pois, no Java, atualmente, a instanciação seria a criação de um objeto, e que tipos primitivos não são instanciáveis. Entendeu como não entendo sua resposta?

Comment: Imagino que tenha problemas de interpretação de texto ou entendimento gramatical e está tirando conclusões que não estão no texto. E acho que está tão preso ao conceito errado que aprendeu que não consegue ler este texto sem um viés. Esqueça todo entendimento errado e leia com calma, prestando atenção, refletindo sobre o que está escrito. Eu editei a outra resposta na pergunta original pra ver se fica mais fácil entender. E sugiro fortemente seguir os *links* que posto para ter um entendimento mais universal sobre o assunto.

Comment: OK, vá com calma. Sou iniciante em Java. E, seu texto não é tão compreensível assim. Deixe-me ver se compreendo o seu pensamento. Você reconhece que em Java tem os tipos primitivos e os por referência, mas no seu modo de pensar todos os dados são objetos, e independe do que está sendo instanciado (tipo por valor ou por referência). Quanto à alocação, você está se referindo ao que conhecemos por stack e heap? Ou seja, o dado, independente da área de memória onde está alocado, é um objeto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, toda essa parte está correta.

Comment: @Maniero, nesse caso então você se refere à instância num sentido meio platônico? Tipo, o 1 é uma representação "material" de um ideal inteiro, portanto ele é uma instância dos inteiros?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso (acho, se eu entendi o que disse). Por que? Tem uma visão diferente?

Comment: @Maniero não, minha visão era essa mesma. Só para por pingos nos i's, confirmar meu entendimento

Comment: Mas é concreto (do ponto de vista da computação, não vou entrar na discussão que no computador tudo é abstrato exceto os elétrons). Porque o `1` de um `int` deveria ser diferente do `1` de um `Integer`, exceto pelo fato que o segundo tem uma referência para ele, e alocado no *heap*, salvo alguma otimização? Ambos são instâncias do meu valor. Apesar de terem o mesmo valor, não possuem identidade, são objetos diferentes, são instâncias distintas do mesmo modelo, um direto e outro indireto.

Comment: @Maniero compreendo seu pensamento, mas gostaria de chamar a atenção para a pergunta que tem em seu contexto a linguagem de programação Java. Atualmente, Java diferencia tipos por valor e tipos por referencia. E, gostaria de ter uma resposta no  contexto que a pergunta se insere.

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira e a resposta considera isso. Alias, ela é toda sobre isso. Eu respondi o que você perguntou. Se fosse especificamente sobre a diferença entre tipos por valor e tipos por referência deveria ter pergunta sobre isso., E a pergunta teria sido fechada como duplicata já quem resposta sobre isso no site. Mas não faria muito sentido ser sobre isso porque o que originou essa pergunta foi https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274048/array-e-o-tipo-que-est%c3%a1-sendo-criado#comment560840_274053. Você ainda está com um viés e não está lendo o que escrevi.

Comment: @Maniero não estou com viés. Estou com a mente aberta para aprender. Levo em consideração todas as respostas e/ou comentários.

Answer (score 2):

O Java possui dois tipos de dados que são divididos em por valor (`tipos primitivos`) e por referência (`tipos por referência`).

Os tipos primitivos são `boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float e double`. Os tipos por referência, são classes que especificam os tipos de objeto Strings, Arrays Primitivos e Objetos.

Uma variável do tipo primitivo pode armazenar exatamente um valor de seu tipo declarado por vez, quando outro valor for atribuído a essa variável, seu valor inicial será substituído.

As variáveis de instância de tipo primitivo são inicializadas por padrão, as variáveis dos tipos `byte, char, short, int, long, float e double` são inicializadas como 0, e as variáveis do tipo `boolean` são inicializadas como false. Esses tipos podem especificar seu próprio valor inicial para uma variável do tipo primitivo atribuindo à variável um valor na sua declaração.

O Java fornece dois tipos primitivos para armazenar números de ponto flutuante na memória, o tipo float e double.

A diferença entre eles é que as variáveis double podem armazenar números com maior magnitude e mais detalhes, ou seja, armazena mais dígitos à direita do ponto de fração decimal, do que as variáveis float. As variáveis do tipo float representam números de ponto flutuante de precisão simples e podem representar até 7 dígitos.

As variáveis do tipo double representam números de ponto flutuante de precisão dupla, onde precisam duas vezes a quantidade de memória das variáveis float fornecendo 15 dígitos, sendo o dobro da precisão de variáveis float. Os valores do tipo double são conhecidos como literais de ponto flutuante. Para números de ponto flutuante precisos, o Java fornece a classe BigDecimal (pacote java.math).

**Listagem 2: Exemplo dos tamanhos de tipos primitivos**

public class Tipos_de_Dados {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Tipos de dados em Java: \n" +
            "\nMenor Byte: " + Byte.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Byte: " + Byte.MAX_VALUE +
            "\nMenor Short Int: " + Short.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Short Int: " + Short.MAX_VALUE +
            "\nMenor Int: " + Integer.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Int: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE +
            "\nMenor Long: " + Long.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Long:" + Long.MAX_VALUE +
            "\nMenor Float: " + Float.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Float: " + Float.MAX_VALUE +
            "\nMenor Double: " + Double.MIN_VALUE +
            "\nMaior Double: " + Double.MAX_VALUE);

}
```

}
**Listagem 3: Declaração dos tipos primitivos**

```
public class Tipos_Primitivos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          byte tipoByte = 127;
          short tipoShort = 32767;
          char tipoChar = 'C';
          float tipoFloat = 2.6f;
          double tipoDouble = 3.59;
          int tipoInt = 2147483647;
          long tipoLong = 9223372036854775807L;
          boolean tipoBooleano = true;
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoByte = " + tipoByte);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoShort = " + tipoShort);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoChar = " + tipoChar); 
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoFloat = " + tipoFloat);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoDouble = " + tipoDouble);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoInt = " + tipoInt);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoLong = " + tipoLong);
          System.out.println("Valor do tipoBooleano = " + tipoBooleano);
    }
}
```

Na Listagem 3 o tipo declarado como char é sempre declarado com aspas simples porque o tamanho é somente de 1 caractere. Os tipos float sempre irão possuir o caractere “f” no final do valor para sua identificação, sendo a mesma coisa com o tipo long só que é inserido o caractere “L”.

Tipos por referência
Os programas utilizam as variáveis de tipos por referência para armazenar as localizações de objetos na memória do computador. Esses objetos que são referenciados podem conter várias variáveis de instância e métodos dentro do objeto apontado.

Para trazer em um objeto os seus métodos de instância, é preciso ter referência a algum objeto. As variáveis de referência são inicializadas com o valor “null” (nulo).

Por exemplo, `ClasseConta acao = new ClasseConta()`, cria um objeto de classe `ClasseConta` e a variável acao contém uma referência a esse objeto `ClasseConta`, onde poderá invocar todos os seus métodos e atributos da classe. A palavra chave new solicita a memória do sistema para armazenar um objeto e inicializa o objeto.

**Listagem 4: Exemplo acessando um método do objeto**

```
public class AcessaMetodo {

    public void imprime(){
        System.out.println("Bem Vindo ao Java!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AcessaMetodo acessa = new AcessaMetodo ();
        acessa.imprime();

    }

}
```

A saída desse código acima irá ser reproduzida através da ação acessa.imprime(), porque está sendo acessado o método do objeto que foi inicializado com a variável definida como “acessa”.

Considerações finais
As variáveis de `tipos por valor não referenciam objetos`, esses tipos de variáveis não podem ser utilizadas para invocar métodos.
Lembrar de que as variáveis locais não são inicializadas por padrão (variáveis dentro dos métodos).
As variáveis do tipo primitivo não podem ser inicializadas como referência a um objeto.

Fonte:https://www.devmedia.com.br/tipos-de-dados-por-valor-e-por-referencia-em-java/25293

[Classes Wrappers em Java](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3667/classes-wrappers-em-java.aspx)

Comment: dentro do contexto em que a pergunta está inserida, sua resposta atende a minha dúvida. "Uma variável do tipo primitivo pode armazenar exatamente um valor de seu tipo declarado por vez, quando outro valor for atribuído a essa variável, seu valor inicial será substituído". "Tipos por referência Os programas utilizam as variáveis de tipos por referência para armazenar as localizações de objetos na memória do computador. Esses objetos que são referenciados podem conter várias variáveis de instância e métodos dentro do objeto apontado."

Comment: sim, @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira

Comment: @AlexandreS.V.Oliveira a pergunta em si não tem contexto algum, ela é muito simples para ter um contexto. O contexto está nos comentários que culminou em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274048/array-e-o-tipo-que-est%c3%a1-sendo-criado/274053?noredirect=1#comment560864_274053. Deveria ter colocado esse contexto. O LR10 não sabia deste contexto. Eu dei a resposta que eu prometi lá. E lá tem um link sobre tipos por valor e tipos por referência. Note que você não usa esses termos em nenhum lugar dessa pergunta, usa dois termos: *tipo primitivo* e *objeto* (minúsculo). Você ainda acha objeto

Comment: é sinônimo de tipo por referência, e tipo primitivo é sinônimo de tipo por valor, e não é. Tudo isto está explicado na minha resposta. Além desta resposta falar de algo fora do contexto real (porque não a pergunta não esclarecia), tem erros nela, apesar de estar certa em boa parte, mas não diz qual é a real diferença entre os dois termos perguntados.

Answer (score -3):

Um tipo de dado primitivo é um tipo de dado predefinido pela linguagem.
Dados primitivos em java são dados dos tipos:

```
byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, e char
```

Objectos são um conceito de programação que tenta se aproximar do conceito de objectos do mundo real.

- Diferentemente dos dados primitivos, objectos não são predefinidos na
  linguagem. É necessário escrever uma classe, que é um molde que define o
  objecto.
- Objectos são em si mesmo dados, e as classes que os definem são tipos
  de dados também.
- Objectos podem conter vários dados de diferentes tipos no seu
  interior. Tipos primitivos não.
- Objectos precisam ser inicializados (usando a palavra new) antes de
  poderem ser utilizados.
- As bibliotecas do Java tem inúmeros tipos de objectos definidos em suas
  classes. Os primitivos por outro lado são limitados.
- O programador pode definir seus próprios objectos, mas não pode fazer
  o mesmo para os primitivos.
- Ojectos também podem ter comportamentos. Podem fazer algo. Os do tipo
  primitivo não.

**Arrays são um tipo especial de objecto. Podem conter tipos primitivos ou outros objectos.**

As bibliotecas do Java vem com vários tipos de dados não primitivos que representam dados primitivos e outros dados de necessidade básica como:

```
Integer, Double, Float, Boolean, Character, String, Date, etc.
```

Nestes casos podemos sempre colocar o primitivo no lugar objecto ou vice versa, e o Java irá converter um tipo no outro.

Exemplo de colocação de um primitivo no lugar de um objecto e vice versa:

```
Integer a=1; // a é um objecto que recebe o valor 1, o valor 1 será convertido para um objecto do tipo Integer
int b= new Integer(2) // o inverso acontece. O objecto do tipo Integer é convertido para o tipo primitivo int
```

Mais exemplos:

```
int a=1; // tipo primitivo inteiro com valor 1
Integer b=1; // objecto inteiro com valor 1
Integer c= new Integer(1); // outro objecto inteiro com valor 1
int z= new Integer(4); // int com valor 4 convertido do Integer

int [] d=new int[5]; // array de dados primitivos
int [] e=new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //outro array de dados primitivos
int [] p=new int[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)}; //outro array de dados primitivos

Integer [] f=new Integer[5]; // array de objectos do tipo inteiro
Integer[]g=new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}; // outro array de objectos do tipo inteiro
Integer[]h=new Integer[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)}; // outro array de objectos do tipo inteiro
```