# Um array de int é um array de objetos?

Tags: java, array, tipagem

`int x = 1;`

não é um objeto é um tipo primitivo, mas

`int[] x = new int[20];`

é um array de objetos, correto? Por que isso?

Comment: ok entendi. obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Java faz essa diferenciação entre instância da classe `Object` e os chamados objetos de "tipo primitivo", que não são instâncias de `Object` mas são objetos (termo de ciência da computação).

Um array `int []`, como todo array em Java, é uma instância de `Object`, porém seus itens são de um tipo primitivo.

Dado `Object [] arr = new ...`, então `arr` é um array de referências para objetos do tipo `Object`. Referências não são objetos, mas podem apontar para eles. Podem também ser nulas conforme o caso.

Por isso em um array de referências (ou de tipos primitivos) você deve inicializar (atribuir um valor a) cada item antes de usar, se isso já não for feito automaticamente (vai depender da situação).

Answer (score 7):

> Não é um objeto é um tipo primitivo

Não, isto está incorreto.

> É um array de objetos. Correto? Por que isso?

Sim, é um *array* de objetos. E agora recomendo dar uma lida sobre [o que é um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). Alguns lugares definem errado e faz as pessoas entenderem equivocamente o que é um objeto.

Se a dúvida é sobre ele ser um *array* de `Object`, aí não, não é.

`Object` é um tipo do Java que define a base para todas as classes que serão usadas na linguagem, ou seja, todas as classes herdarão deste tipo.

Inclusive o próprio *array* herda de `Object`.

Isso é uma ideia boa, e já que Java decidiu desde sua concepção que seria o mais orientada a objeto possível, fazia todo sentido que todos os tipos fossem derivados de um tipo principal.

Os tipos que são classes são tipos por referência, portanto são alocados no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), que tem um gerenciamento complexo e lento. É tudo feito pelo [*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101).

Quando estavam criando a linguagem perceberam que isso não era desejável e resolveram criar tipos por valor. Eles foram chamados de tipos primitivos, ainda que [a definição se o termo é correto é questionável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101). Está errado achar que se não herda de `Object` é um primitivo. Por acaso isso acontece em Java, mas não é a definição de tipo primitivo, não há essa oposição. Pior ainda é achar que tipo primitivo não é um objeto. Se ele não é um objeto, é o que então? É o vácuo? Objeto e primitivo são conceitos diferentes e que podem estar no mesmo... objeto.

Então os tipos primitivos não foram herdados de `Object` já que eles possuem semântica diferente. Mas tipos primitivos continuam criando objetos, sem herdar de qualquer outro tipo. Isso quebra a orientação a objeto de Java. Como ocorre em muitas linguagem, mas algumas nunca tentaram ser OO ou se vender como tendo qualidade.

[Java quer mudar isso e está criando uma forma de tipos por valor poderem ser criados pelo usuário (o programador)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101). Precisamos esperar sair para ver tudo o que conseguiram fazer. O ideal é que os tipos por valor também herdem de `Object`. E dá para fazer isso, C# fez. Você trata esses tipos de maneira especial pela linguagem. Se não fizerem isso o mecanismo ficará bem ruim e não solucionará muito o problema.

Em tese os chamados tipos primitivos vão agir como um tipo geral e deveriam, quando tiver esse novo mecanismo, herdar de `Object`, então algumas coisas podem mudar na linguagem, sem quebrar a compatibilidade, e isso é que torna isso difícil de conceber.

Não esqueça de ver todos os *links*, inclusive das respostas *linkadas* aqui para entender melhor tudo isso.

Tenho a impressão que a pergunta é duplicata de [Diferença entre tipo primitivo e objeto em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274391/101).

Answer (score -2):

Não não, um array de int não é um array de objetos. É um array de dados primitivos do tipo int.

```
int x = 1; // primitivo do tipo int (inteiro)
int[] x = new int[20]; // array de primitivos do tipo int

Integer x=1; // objecto do tipo Integer (inteiro)
Integer []x=new Integer[20]; // array de objectos do tipo inteiro
```

Pode encontrar explicação detalhada nesta outra pergunta: [Diferença entre tipo primitivo e objeto em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274391/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-tipo-primitivo-e-objeto-em-java/530928#530928)