# Por que uma variável de referência guarda o endereço e não o objeto em si?

Tags: variáveis, objetos, memória

Entendi que quando instanciamos um objeto, guardamos uma referência ao objeto e não o objeto em si, mas por que isso acontece? Por exemplo, em variáveis primitivas guardamos diretamente o valor na variável, por que com objetos não acontece o mesmo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Entendi que quando instanciamos um objeto, guardamos uma referência ao objeto

Não, quando instanciamos um objeto criamos esse objeto e guardamos em algum lugar. Onde exatamente depende da linguagem e da forma como explicitamos onde deve ser armazenado, se a linguagem permitir isto.

Primeiro vamos entender [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) já que a maioria entende errado o que é isto.

E vamos entender [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Se não entender os termos ou entender errado não tem como aprender adequadamente.

Então alguns objetos são instanciados e armazenados na variável, outros são armazenados em outro local, geralmente o [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e a variável recebe um ponteiro ([referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)) para o objeto, isto chama-se [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Entendendo indireção e a limitação da pilha, lendo todos os *links* acima, fica fácil entender o foco da pergunta e porque é útil fazer assim.

E aí podemos desmistificar o que é [tipo primitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101) (variável primitiva não existe). [Também ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274391/101). Os objetos primitivos (dependendo da definição, se `string` for considerado primitivo, já não cabe aqui, já que não se sabe o tamanho dela) e outros tipos simples não primitivos costumam ter tamanho e tempo de vida bem definidos, fora que eles não possuem hierarquia. Objetos primitivos ainda são objetos.

Então a premissa da pergunta está errada.

Ocorre que alguns objetos tem tamanhos indefinidos ou são conhecidamente muito grandes, em alguns casos não se sabe exatamente qual é o objeto que está sendo criado, ainda que se sabe a que hierarquia ele pertence (em algumas linguagens nunca sabe), e ainda não é sabido qual o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) desse objeto. Com toda essa incerteza ter uma indireção é a única solução plausível.

> Não existe problema na computação que não possa ser resolvido com um
> nível extra de indireção
>
> -- David J. Wheeler

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).