# Diferença de tipo primitivo e tipo simples em C#

Tags: c#, .net, terminologia, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Eu estava lendo sobre tipos em Java e tentei comparar com o C#. Eu sei que cada linguagem tem conceitos próprios ou tratem de problemas iguais de maneira diferente, mas tenho curiosidade quanto a esse tipo de comparação.

Para o Java encontrei a seguinte afirmação:

> "Os tipos dos objetos são determinados pela classe de origem. Em nome
> da eficiência e da simplicidade. **Java ainda oferece os seguintes
> tipos básicos (também chamados de tipos primitivos) que não são
> objetos** [boolean, char, byte, short, int, long, float e double]".

Quanto à parte do objeto  entendi que em Java os tipos primitivos não são objeto, mas em C# são objetos.

Porém, ao tentar encontrar os tipos primitivos equivalentes em C# comecei a ficar confuso com a terminologia dentro do mundo Dot Net.

Encontrei neste site (https://www.macoratti.net/17/01/cshp_primit1.htm) que "tipos primitivos" não fazem parte da especificação da linguagem C#, mas sim da CLI.

Lendo algumas respostas daqui [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356647/o-que-%C3%A9-considerado-primitivo-em-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), [Diferença entre tipo primitivo e objeto em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274391/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-tipo-primitivo-e-objeto-em-java) e conferindo a documentação citada (ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)) vi que há diversas referências a "tipos primitivos" e que na (ECMA-334 - C# Language Specification, item 8.3.5) não há referência a "tipos primitivos", mas há a referência a "tipos simples":

> “C# fornece um conjunto de tipos struct predefinidos chamados de **tipos
> simples**. Os tipos simples são identificados por meio de
> palavras-chave, mas essas palavras-chave são simplesmente aliases para
> tipos struct predefinidos no namespace System, conforme descrito na
> tabela abaixo."

Diante disso tinha chegado à conclusão que os "tipos primitivos" são os tipos da CLI e os "tipos simples" do C# são os tipos da CLI com um apelido.

Porém ao ler esta página (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da documentação da Microsoft, vi que não tinha entendido nada.

> "C# tem um sistema de tipo unificado. Todos os tipos do C#, **incluindo
> tipos primitivos**, como int e double, herdam de um único tipo de object
> raiz. Assim, todos os tipos compartilham um conjunto de operações
> comuns, e valores de qualquer tipo podem ser armazenados,
> transportados e operados de maneira consistente. Além disso, C#
> oferece suporte a tipos de referência e tipos de valor definidos pelo
> usuário, permitindo a alocação dinâmica de objetos, bem como o
> armazenamento em linha de estruturas leves."

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- O que seriam os "tipos primitivos" em C# (ou no Dot Net)?
- Eles são sinônimos de "tipos simples" e "tipo de valor interno"? Ou
  são apenas as estruturas da CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que bom que você entende que cada tecnologia tem sua própria definição. Eu já falei sobre isso em algumas postagens, veja os *links* abaixo.

C# é mais cuidadosa que a maioria das linguagens em várias coisas, inclusive a especificação. Não quer dizer que não tenha erros, mas eles tentaram acertar mais, e corrigem quando algo está errado. C# sabe que primitivo é um termo ruim, até porque ele não é universal.

C# e outras linguagens possuem mais ou menos os mesmos tipos mais importantes, com nomes diferentes, com especificações um pouco divergentes, algumas linguagens preferem não ter todos eles, pode ser por uma boa razão, e podem classificá-los como quiser, se fizer sentido. Dar algum nome diferente não significa necessariamente que seja outra coisa.

CLI existe para atender várias linguagens, não transporte o conceito dele para a linguagem. Você nem precisa saber que CLI existe para usar C#.

Eu sempre falo para as pessoas usarem conteúdo original em inglês e não em português. Essa página não tem equivalente idêntica em inglês. Em inglês não fala nada disso. Pode ser que esta ficou largada, pode ser que alguém colocou isso, ninguém revisou. Claramente aí o termo está sendo usado em substituição a "tipos por valor".

C# não usa o termo primitivo para tipos. O mais próximo do conceito é o "tipo simples" que é um termo menos ambíguo, mas não quer dizer que seja a mesma coisa, a definição deste último está na especificação e reproduzida na pergunta.

Se você ler abaixo verá como é complicado, terá que fazer uma avaliação para entender o que poderia ser primitivo em C#, se você quisesse classificar assim. Sua interpretação poderá fazer variar o resultado. Até por não ter uma única definição.

O CLR adotou tanto isso que tem em código/API o que é primitivo. E é fácil saber o que é primitivo, é o que ele definiu o que é. Só isso. O critério que costuma usar para ser parece que é o tipo ser nativo do processador. Nada comprova essa ideia, é suposição pelo que foi definido antes e ainda é hoje, e parece que sempre será. Mas vai saber porque `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr` e outros tipos nativos do processador não são.

Não tente transpor nada disso para outra tecnologia.

- [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101)
- [Escalar, primitivo, nativo ou atômico ou por valor, é tudo a mesma coisa entre tipos de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575246/101)
- [Por que os tipos de dados primitivos são fixos em tamanho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559752/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).