# Existe algum nome para o "boolean de 3 estados"?

Tags: terminologia, booleano

#### Mas como assim um "boolean de 3 estados"?

Geralmente é usado na comparação entre datas, em que os resultados possíveis são `-1`, `0`, `1`.

Estava em uma situação similar e fiquei com essa dúvida ao querer indagar meu colega a respeito de uma possível representação `Enum` em Java.

Comment: Nunca vi este termo, seria 3 estados? Pode citar um exemplo de uso com comparação de datas.

Comment: Lógica trivalorada?

Comment: @Maniero se entendi bem, a ideia é a mesma aplicada na função [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) do C, que tem os 3 possíveis retornos; ou da utilizada pelo [*spaceship operator*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) no PHP.

Comment: @rray parece bom, mas então de fato não tem um nome? ja que você esta indagando.

Comment: Já ouviu esse termo em banco de dados, no caso uma coluna pode ter algum valor, nada e null (desconhecido).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, mas não tem nada de booleano de 3 estados (ou fases) ali.

Comment: Pois é, cabe ao @GuilhermeLautert afirmar melhor o que perguntou. Ao meu ver, o termo "booleano de 3 estados" foi utilizado de forma equivocada, mesmo sem intenção, o que acabou, possivelmente, desviando a pergunta. Ou entendi errado :D

Comment: Me colega achou a seguinte na [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) que me parece bem interessante. "Ternário Balanceado"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um booleano de 3 estados é o que tem o falso, o verdadeiro e o indefinido. Então em Java existe um natural que é o `Boolean`, não confundir com `boolean` ([Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101)). O primeiro aceita um `null`, então há um terceiro estado.

Em C# pode usar um `bool?`. Tem linguagem que só tem o booleano de 3 estados, e muita gente nem se dá conta disto.

Em linguagens que não possuem isso precisaria criar uma convenção ou até uma enumeração se existir na linguagem, algo assim:

```
enum tribool { false, true, maybe = -1 }
```

Algumas pessoas dizem que isso não deveria ser usado, e que se tem 3 estados então não é um booleano, é outra coisa. De fato nessa coisa de data me parece ser outra coisa. Algo assim:

```
enum compara { igual, depois, antes = -1 }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Enum3States.ptg).

> Existe algum nome para o “boolean de 3 fases”?

Aparentemente é chamada de lógica trivalente ou ternária (afinal a booleana é a binária), [segundo a Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_tern%C3%A1ria) ([em inglês mais completo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)). Outros termos podem ser usados como visto nos comentários. Não parece haver um nome universal. E como o seu uso não é tão incentivado assim, pode ser melhor assim.

Pelo que entendi ninguém recebeu o crédito pela "invenção" e por isso ninguém foi homenageado. A binária poderia não chamar booleana se não dessem tanto crédito ao George Boole.

Comment: De fato fases, não esta certo, estados parece melhor mesmo. Eu coloquei o que pensei na hora.

Comment: Acho que você pode gostar de ver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Comment: É a versão em inglês da página que eu *linkei* :)